# Char * в WCHAR

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Есть кусок кода, который по факту работает в одной из более ранних версий VC++, но в 12 получается следующее:

```
LOGFONT logfont;
strcpy(logfont.lfFaceName, "Arial");
```

где lfFaceName является WCHAR[32] и ругается

```
невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "WCHAR [32]" в "char *"
```

И с какой стати **ИЗ** WCHAR  **В** char *, если функция копирует из второго аргумента-указателя в первый?

Comment: @Ni55aN, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать `lstrcpy`.
Правильно так:

```
lstrcpy(logfont.lfFaceName, _T("Arial"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Может, поможет такая запись:

```
#include <tchar.h>
...
LOGFONT logfont;
strcpy(logfont.lfFaceName, _T("Arial"));
...
```

То есть с добавлением `_T()`.